# One OkHttpClient with all Interceptors vs. multiple OkHttpClients with specific Interceptors

Tags: android, retrofit2, okhttp

I have a number of different request interceptors for an OkHttpClient. Each interceptor is only required for a subset of the network requests that the app makes. So far I've come up with two possible designs. Should I:

- Attach every interceptor to a single OkHttpClient client.

OR

- Clone the client for each group of interceptors such that each OkHttpClient has only the interceptors that are required for those requests.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I would argue for the first case because it is

1. Simpler for client use, only one client to manage.
2. Simpler for cleanup (closing dispatcher, connection pool)
3. works with redirects across host.

Just make each interceptor use a conditional check.

AFAIK connection pools can be shared across OkHttpClient instances that you clone e.g. client.newBuilder().x(...).build(), provided that you don't do things like change the SSLContext.

Comment: Thanks Yuri, my main concern with this approach is the performance concern of running every request through the entire interceptor chain.

Comment: Is it possible to have multiple clients share the same resources(closing dispatcher and connection pool)?

Comment: If performance is critical, then you can benchmark both approaches.  However, I'm pretty sure that I/O and other activity in OkHttp would dwarf even 10-20 interceptors.

Comment: newBuilder shares resources.  See https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/OkHttpClient.html

"Customize your client with newBuilder()"